# Adding a picture box behind a Transparent Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, panel, picturebox

I have two panels on top of each other. The one below is a bit larger than the one on top. I am painting an image by using CreateGraphics() method on the top most panel. (To be clear this image is a connect four grid with transparent holes). Now what I need to do is to add a picture box to the bottom panel and have it show from behind this grid.

I am adding controls of picture box to the bottom grid. And I'm using the BringToFront() method too. What can I do to have the picture box show underneath the grid?

In the following code: chipHolder is the bottom panel, grid is the topmost panel and picBox is the picture box respectively

```
public void addControl()
{
   chipHolder.Controls.Add(picBox);
   picBox.BringToFront();
}

// This piece of code is in a mouse_click event of grid 
Graphics g = grid.CreateGraphics();
addControl();

// to make the picture move downwards
for (int i = 0; i < newYloc; i++)
{
     picBox.Location = new Point(newXloc, picBox.Top + 1);
     picBox.Show();
}

// drawing the grid image on the grid panel
protected virtual void grid_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
     Image img = Properties.Resources.grid_fw;

     gridGraphics = grid.CreateGraphics();
     gridGraphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 650, 550);
}
```

To have a better picture this is how my panels are. the one selected is the chipHolder panel.

[image]

Comment: If you want all these layering effects to work then you should really switch to WPF.  There is very little point in putting a picturebox behind a panel that you paint.  Just draw the image in the panel's Paint event handler first.

Comment: I can't draw the image in the panel's paint event handler cause I want to see the chip go down when the user clicks on the grid :/ So this isnt possible with winforms?

Comment: Maybe you could use this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window.

Answer (score 2):

You could try a different approach: don't use a *Panel* and use a single *PictureBox*, this way you draw everything in that *PictureBox*. Thus, you use PictureBox's **MouseDown** event handler to calculate the (virtual) cell the user has clicked (you need to perform a simple division) and then you draw the chip on the *PictureBox*. If you want to show the chip falling, you'd need to save a copy of the current *Bitmap* (the *Image* property of the *PictureBox*) and draw the chip on different **y** coordinates (from 0 to its final position on the grid), this would be just like the double-buffer technique.

Here is a small example (you need a *Form* with a *PictureBox*, in this example it's named "pictureBox2"):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap chip = new Bitmap(40, 40, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(chip))
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 80, 0)), 1, 1, 38, 38);
        }
        pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox2.Width, pictureBox2.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox2.Image))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Yellow);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Text = e.Location.ToString();
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox2.Image))
            {
                g.DrawImage(chip, e.Location.X - 20, e.Location.Y - 20);
            }
            pictureBox2.Invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

If you want controls with real transparency, you should use **WPF** (it provides better graphics and uses hardware acceleration).

Comment: This is what I am currently doing in my grid panel.. but instead of using Mouse_Down, I use Mouse_Click, and I use a panel for the grid and a picture box for the chip. So if I understand you correctly, I can try and use a picture box for the grid and just draw the bitmap of the chip on it. But wouldn't that mean that the chip will be in front of the grid if I add the grid to the picbox first? Also, wouldn't Invalidate() sort of clear the grid then? Thanks for your detailed answer :)

Comment: Basically you need to update the whole image. So you have to draw every _layer_ of your scene in order, from back to front: 1) Draw the background 2) Draw the chip 3) Draw the grid. Then you invalidate the _PictureBox_ to see the updated scene. BTW, with _MouseClick_ you can clic a mouse button, then if you move the mouse while the button is still pressed and finally you release the button on a different position, _MouseClick_ returns this last position (not the position where you initially clicked).